# Polarizing cavity dumped laser light

Tags: optics

From what I have read, most lasers are polarized because of Brewster windows. However, cavity dumped laser light never interacts with Brewster windows. Now, I know that there have been many cases of polarized cavity dumped laser light. So, what methods do physicists use to polarize cavity dumped lasers? Do these methods reduce the intensity of the laser light?

Comment: Many gas or dye lasers might be polarized due to Brewster mirrors. But the vast majority of lasers manufactured every year are diode lasers. Diode lasers are generally polarized because the cavity is a waveguide and it is typically  asymmetrical, leading to preferential lasing in one polarization or the other.

Comment: so would gas lasers be polarized without the Brewster windows?

Comment: TBH, I don't know enough about cavity dumped lasers to answer definitively. But after reading the article on rp-photonics, it seems that during the build up phase of a cavity-dumped laser, it should be possible to use a Brewster window to build up one polarization preferentially, and the polarization should not change dramatically during the dumping phase. So I'm curious why it should be that "cavity dumped laser light never interacts with Brewster windows"? Can you point out a resource that explains it?